# Responsive vertical/horizontal heading table with toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

I have a table that has vertical and horizontal headings. I want to achieve that each row will be greouped together on mobile. Each row's heading will be the main title so to say and it would contain all the top heading with the corresponding row data.

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="empty"></th>
      <th>0-50</th>
      <th>0-75</th>
      <th>0-100</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>BMW M3</th>
      <td>4.2</td>
      <td>4.9</td>
      <td>5.7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BMW M4</th>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td>4.6</td>
      <td>5.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Mercedes AMG E63</th>
      <td>4.4</td>
      <td>4.9</td>
      <td>5.9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This table would look like this:

```
BMW M3
-------
0-50 4.2
0-75 4.9
0-100 5.7
-------

BMW M4
-------
0-50 4.1
0-75 4.6
0-100 5.4
-------

Mercedes AMG E63
-------
0-50 4.4
0-75 4.9
0-100 5.9
-------
```

I don't want to solve this with predefined content before in css, since the tables will be dynamic. I don't mind if its a javascript/jquery solution - I tried with datatables, but didn't manage to get this kind of result.

Only 1 table can be used - using 2 tables and hide/show them is not an option in this case.

Comment: But I think here the problem is basicly your html table structure. But are you getting it this way, or you are the one making it ? Because I think most simple will be to make 2 tables in html and display one for mobile and one for computer

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use 2 tables. This is what i have to work with. Somehow transform this 1 table

Comment: Ok I guess you should add this info into your question. It is quite challenging then

Comment: I'll edit and add that

Comment: That's not how tables work, unfortunately. You _might_ be able to approximate what you're trying to do by setting the `display` rule to `block` for pretty much every table element (table, tr, th, tbody, thead, and td), but that a) probably isn't going to work with the DataTables plugin and b) might break the semantics of the table for screen-readers (if accessibility is a concern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you a solution with css and html.

You play with display as in DEMO below. For demo I just reproduce it with BMW 3 but I guess you can easily make it for the other as well.

DEMO with 2 tables (will change at 680px width):

```css
.computer{
  display: table;
}
.mobile{
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:680px){
  .computer{
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile{
    display:table;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table computer">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="empty"></th>
      <th>0-50</th>
      <th>0-75</th>
      <th>0-100</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>BMW M3</th>
      <td>4.2</td>
      <td>4.9</td>
      <td>5.7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BMW M4</th>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td>4.6</td>
      <td>5.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Mercedes AMG E63</th>
      <td>4.4</td>
      <td>4.9</td>
      <td>5.9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table mobile">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">BMW M3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0-50</th>
      <td>4.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>0-75</th>
      <td>4.9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>0-100</th>
      <td>5.7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In Demo 2, I added directly lines correctly organised, directly into your original table. As you did not mention if you can or not make that. If you cannot do that then yeah, it should be js and quite a job, as I commented below your question.

### DEMO 2 with 1 table

```css
.computer{
  display: table;
}
.mobile{
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:680px){
  .computer{
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile{
    display:table;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="computer">
    <tr>
      <th class="empty"></th>
      <th>0-50</th>
      <th>0-75</th>
      <th>0-100</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="computer">
      <th>BMW M3</th>
      <td>4.2</td>
      <td>4.9</td>
      <td>5.7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="computer">
      <th>BMW M4</th>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td>4.6</td>
      <td>5.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="computer">
      <th>Mercedes AMG E63</th>
      <td>4.4</td>
      <td>4.9</td>
      <td>5.9</td>
    </tr>
    <!------- [START] Mobile ----------->
    <tr class="mobile">
      <th colspan="2">BMW M3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mobile">
      <th>0-50</th>
      <td>4.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mobile">
      <th>0-75</th>
      <td>4.9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mobile">
      <th>0-100</th>
      <td>5.7</td>
    </tr>
    <!------- [END] Mobile ----------->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

DEMO 3 is your original table that we custom with JS. To get final result as demo 2:

### DEMO 3 Inspire from demo 2 with js dynamic:

```js
var tbodyTr = $('tbody > tr');

tbodyTr.each(function(){
  
  var theadMobile = $(this).find('th');

  $('tbody > tr:last').after('<tr class="mobile"></tr>');
  $('tbody > tr:last').append('<th></th>');
  $('tbody > tr:last > th').append(theadMobile.html());

  var i = 1;
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    var thHeaders = $('thead > tr > th').eq(i).html();
  
    $('tbody > tr:last').after('<tr class="mobile"></tr>');
    $('tbody > tr:last').append('<th></th>');
    $('tbody > tr:last > th').append(thHeaders);
    $('tbody > tr:last').append($(this).html());

    i++;
  });
});

$('thead').addClass('computer');
$('tbody > tr').each(function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass("mobile"))
    $(this).addClass('computer');
});
```

```css
.computer{
  display: table;
}
.mobile{
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:680px){
  .computer{
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile{
    display:table;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="empty"></th>
      <th>0-50</th>
      <th>0-75</th>
      <th>0-100</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>BMW M3</th>
      <td>4.2</td>
      <td>4.9</td>
      <td>5.7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BMW M4</th>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td>4.6</td>
      <td>5.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Mercedes AMG E63</th>
      <td>4.4</td>
      <td>4.9</td>
      <td>5.9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I agree with you, maybe its a solution if he wont need to using a blocks element...vote up +1

Comment: Unfortunately i have to use only 1 table. Ofc this would be a simple solution, but thats what I have to work with. Thats also why i attempted with datatables

Comment: @mheonyae Now I made 2 solution, with 1 table but I guess what you need is the last demo. Finaly I was really thinking to make it simple without so much code

Comment: Yeah solves the mobile part, but messes up the desktop one, as its empty. Guess if I clone every element before append it sohuld do the trick

Comment: @mheonyae here I adjusted it by using `html()` and seems fine now. I don't think that you have any otherway

Comment: Yes, indeed, i flagged it as answer.